# Some guidance with C++ and creating objects using composition

Tags: c++, oop, object, composition, class-design

Basically my issue is with compositions. I understand the principle, but I'm struggling with the execution in one of the tests.

From the code of `Computer` and `Monitor` below, I have to create a final class `Complect` which will have its own name , the name of the computer, the name of the monitor, and a price which will be made up from the `price()` functions.

Computer.h

```
#ifndef COMPUTER_H
#define COMPUTER_H
#include <string>

class Computer{

public:
    Computer(std::string name, int ram, double price); 

    std::string name() const; 
    int ram() const;
    double price() const;


    void printComputer() const;

    void setComputer(std::string name, int ram, double price);

private:
    std::string its_name;
    int ram_gb;

    double cost_price;
};
#endif // COMPUTER_H
```

Computer.cpp

```
#include "Computer.h"
#include <iostream>

Computer::Computer(std::string name, int ram, double price)
: its_name(name), ram_gb(ram), cost_price(price){
}

std::string Computer::name() const {
    return its_name;
}

int Computer::ram() const {
    return ram_gb;
}

double Computer::price() const {
    return cost_price;
}

void Computer::printComputer() const{ 
    std::cout << "Computer name = " <<name() <<"\n"
    << "Computer RAM = " <<ram() <<" GB\n"
    << "Computer Price = " << price() <<" EUR \n";
}
```

Monitor.h

```
#ifndef MONITOR_H
#define MONITOR_H
#include <string>

class Monitor{

public:
    Monitor(std::string name, std::string type, double price);

    std::string name() const;
    std::string type() const;
    double price() const;

    //print computer
    void printMonitor() const;

    //set computer
    void setMonitor(std::string name, std::string type, double price);

private:
    std::string its_name;
    std::string type_set;

    double cost_price;
};

#endif // MONITOR_H
```

Monitor.cpp

```
#include "Monitor.h"
#include <iostream>

Monitor::Monitor(std::string name, std::string type, double price) : its_name(name), type_set(type), cost_price(price){
}

std::string Monitor::name() const {
    return its_name;
}

std::string Monitor::type() const{
    return type_set;
}

double Monitor::price() const {
    return cost_price;
}

void Monitor::printMonitor() const{
    std::cout << "Monitor name = " <<name() <<"\n"
    << "Monitor type = " <<type() <<"\n"
    << "Monitor price = " << price() <<" EUR \n";
}
```

Here is the class that I have made:

Complect.h

```
#ifndef COMPLECT_H
#define COMPLECT_H
#include <string>

class Complect{

public:
    Complect(std::string name, std::string computername, std::string monitorname,  double price);
    std::string name() const;
    std::string computername() const;
    std::string monitorname() const;
    double price() const;

    void printComplect();

    void setComplect(std::string name, std::string computername, std::string monitorname, double price);

private:
    std::string complect_name;
    std::string computername_final;
    std::string monitorname_final;
    double cost_price;

};

#endif // COMPLECT_H
```

Complect.cpp

```
#include "Complect.h"
#include "Monitor.h"
#include "Computer.h"
#include <iostream>

Complect::Complect(std::string name, std::string computername, std::string monitorname, double price) :
complect_name(name), computername_final(computername), monitorname_final(monitorname), cost_price(price){
}

std::string Complect::name() const{
    return complect_name;
}

std::string Complect::computername() const{
    return computername_final;
}

std::string Complect::monitorname() const{
    return monitorname_final;
}

double Complect::price() const{
    return cost_price;
}

void Complect::printComplect(){
    std::cout << "Complect name = " << name() <<"\n"
    << "Computer name = " <<computername() <<"\n"
    <<"Monitor name = " <<monitorname() <<"\n"
    <<"Complect price = " <<price() <<" EUR \n";
}
```

Here is how I use the classes in Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Computer.h"
#include "Monitor.h"
#include "Complect.h"

int main(){

    Computer asus("Asus One", 8, 545.95) ;
    asus.printComputer() ; 
    std::cout << "\n";

    Monitor iiyama("Iiyama Blackhawk 27inch", "LED", 299.99);
    iiyama.printMonitor();
    std::cout <<"\n";

    Complect numberOne ("Number one complect", asus.name(), iiyama.name(), iiyama.price() + asus.price());
    numberOne.printComplect();
    std::cout <<"\n";

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The end result is what it should be, so this code works.
But the issue with this is that it's incorrectly structured.

In the `main.cpp` file you will see that the `Complect` object is being created.  But I currently provide all of the informations of that object at construction in `main.cpp` file.

Sorry the codes a bit messy, but im trying to wrap my head around this and struggling at the moment...  How to make the class in `complect.cpp` file provide itself all its information ?

Comment: _the codes a bit messy_ not at all, it is clean, compile without warning and using const method, so rare, so I upvote it .. before to answer

Comment: Guys I really do not understand why you want to close that question, it is a serious question and it absolutely not out of the scope of S.O. questions :-)

Comment: I have slightly edited the question so to better highlight your issue and remove a couple of ambiguous formulations.  Please check if it's still ok for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you do not use composition but copy the attributes from the two other classes and you do a lot of work in the call of the constructor from main

A first little change from your code is to get instances of *Computer* and *Monitor* in parameter in the constructor:

```
Complect(std::string name, const Computer &, const Monitor &);
```

of course the final price is also computed inside that constructor, in *main* you just create a *Complect* with its name and its parts :

```
Complect numberOne ("Number one complect", asus, iiyama);
```

Now *main* fortunately does not have to know how the price is computed, else imagine if the formula change and you have to update all the calls of the constructor :-(. The way the price is computed is only the responsibility of *Complect*.

```
Complect numberOne ("Number one complect", asus, iiyama);
```

More than the constructor *setComplect* must be updated to receive the price of the monitor and computer separated for the same reason.

```
void setComplect(std::string name, std::string computername, std::string monitorname, double computerprice, double monitorprice);
```

or probably better to replace it by the methods

```
void setname(std::string name);
void setcomputer(std::string computername, double computerprice);
void setmonitor(std::string monitorname, double monitorprice);
```

---

But to duplicate all the attributes of *Computer* and *Monitor* in *Complect* is not practical, and you do not have composition to the instances. A first possibility is to save a copy of them :

```
class Complect{
  ...
  private:
     Computer computer;
     Monitor monitor;
     // does not need attribute "double cost_price;"
  ...
};

Complect::Complect(std::string name, const Computer & c, const Monitor & m)
   : complect_name(name), computer(c), monitor(m) {
}

std::string Complect::computername() const{
    return computer.name();
}

std::string Complect::monitorname() const{
    return monitor.name();
}

double Complect::price() const{
    return computer.price() + monitor.price();
}

void Complect::printComplect(){
    std::cout << "Complect name = " << name() <<"\n"
    << "Computer name = " << computer.name() <<"\n"
    <<"Monitor name = " << monitor.name() <<"\n"
    <<"Complect price = " << price() <<" EUR \n";
}
```

The advantage of that solution is you are not impacted if the initial instances of *Monitor* and *Computer* disappear. The disadvantage is for instance the price is not updated if the price of one of the cloned part changes except by  calling *setXXX*

---

An other way is to not clone the Monitor and Conputer, but you cannot have just that :

```
class Complect{
  ...
  private:
     Computer & computer;
     Monitor & monitor;
     // does not need attribute "double cost_price;"
  ...
};

Complect::Complect(std::string name, const Computer & c, const Monitor & m)
   : complect_name(name), computer(c), monitor(m) {
}
```

because that supposes the instances of *Monitor* and *Computer* still exist while the corresponding instance of *Complect* exists

Fortunately C++ offers interesting features to manage that

Comment: This makes so much more sense now.... Thanks Bruno.
With this, its working now in this way.

Comment: @B.Baxter ok, I edited again my answer after your accept and I let you continue :-)

Comment: A nice, didactic and helpful answer for people less familiar with C++/oop, and who are also welcome on SO.  Well done !

Comment: @Christophe thank you, I was about to continue speaking about `shared_ptr` etc but the OP stopped me accepting my answer :-)